# Elementary OS does not suspend

Tags: release-juno, updates, suspend

When I click at the suspend button the screen goes black, then I hear a bell ringing (probably wired network turning on) and at the end the screen returns to the login prompt (pantheon).

This happened after upgrading with apt-get distro-upgrade (maybe some ubuntu configuration?).

Is this some problem with ACPI? Is there some easy configuration that will fix it?

Answer (score 0):

For me at least, doing:

```
#echo EHC1 > /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

Fixed it. But it was the Bluetooth waking the machine after a second or two of suspend. I'd cat the file, and try disabling the values one at a time, followed by an attempt at suspending the machine.

Changes to the file are NOT persistent, so everything in it will be changed to default on reboot. If you find the change that makes the difference, make a systemd .service files that runs the command upon boot.

Comment: Sometimes computers creeps me, once the computer woke from I getting close to it. These non deterministic events bothers me so much.

Comment: They may seem none determinist, but they aren't really (well usually) it's often just quirks of the hardware. I urge you to test of this works for you though

Comment: Sometimes it happens sometimes it doesn't. I'll try when it happens.

Comment: not sure what `EHC1` is, but somehow I cant do that code, `permission denied` even with sudo.

Comment: It's because it uses a redirect. Log in as root in the terminal, that is what the `#` in front of the command means: do this as root. You can login to root by doing `sudo su` just remember to `logout` as soon as you are done.